# Clicking Reset password link redirects to login screen

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

here is my GET requests

`http://localhost:8001/password/reset?token=11a1e66a78bd542b8021b31c8ba914a3ee8a556611b82fb187247d4c440a3b6f`

here is my routes

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
    Route::post('api/v1/password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    Route::get('api/v1/password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
});
```

but when placing breakpoints, the flow does not reach `getReset` inside `PasswordController`.

It just redirects to the login screen `http://localhost:8001/#/login`

Im not sure what other info is needed.

*EXTRA*
Im not using Laravel's out of the box form etc. I have React as a front end, so I just need to get into the `getReset` function and will no the rest from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GET Request needs to be

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/password/reset/11a1e66a78bd542b8021b31c8ba914a3ee8a556611b82fb187247d4c440a3b6f
```

Because laravel can't find what route you are searching for.

If you want the GET Request unchanged then you can edit your route

```
 Route::get('api/v1/password/reset/', 'Auth\PasswordController@getReset');
```

Just remove the `{token}`

Comment: Wow, kinda obvious now looking at it hey. Thanks